# How do I verify ssl / tls connection with openssl non-interactively (from a script)?

Tags: openssl, ssl

When I execute:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
openssl s_client -connect government.ru:443
```

This gives me valuable output, but I would like `openssl` to close the connection and exit returning an integer exit code (different in) so that I could do something like this

```
echo "Domain?";read d
openssl s_client -connect "$d":443

if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Encrypted"; do_something
else 
  echo "Plain."; do_something_else
fi
```

Comment: note that the failure to establish a TLS connection on port 443 doesn't mean there's an unencrypted service there or somewhere else. All it means is that TLS on 443 doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s_client` recognize the `Q` command. [openssl docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-s_client.html):

> ```
> Q:  End the current SSL connection and exit.
> ```

```
printf "Q" | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
```

or:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
```

or:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 <<< "Q"
```

Comment: Thanks. It end a successfully established connection (to `google.com`). But it hangs when a domain without a valid certificate such as `government.ru` is given.

Comment: @JohnSmith Use `timeout` to make the command exit after `n` seconds.: `timeout 5 openssl ...`

Comment: I had to rewrite it: `timeout 5 openssl s_client -connect "$d":443 < <(printf "Q\n")` for the script to work.

Comment: @JohnSmith see my edit

Answer (score 2):

If you run `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443` and the TLS connection is successful, the command will wait for data on standard input, for sending over the connection.

If you run `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 </dev/null` and the connection is successful, it will be immediately closed, and you'll get the behaviour you're looking for.